# wrong argument type Class (expected Module) Rails 5 splitting up routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, routes

As the title suggests I'm splitting up my routes file, I have 7 split files, the first 6 work and the routes have been extended to those files, however, for some reason one of the files doesn't work.

This is what I have

`routes.rb`

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ..
  extend Crm # works
  extend Customers # works
  extend Suppliers # works
  extend Employees # works
  extend Bank # doesn't work
  extend Accounts # works
  extend Admin # works
  ..
end
```

I have the following in the `config/routes/bank.rb` file

```rb
module Bank
  def self.extended(router)
    router.instance_exec do
      # bank routes
      resources :bank_accounts, except: %i[destory] do
        member do
          get :import_transactions
          get :reconcile
          post :process_reconcile
        end

        collection do
          get :list
          post :import_transactions_confirm
          post :process_import_transactions_confirm
          get :transfer
          post :process_transfer
          get :revalue_currency_bank_account
          post :process_revalue_currency_bank_account
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is the same layout for all the other files so I'm unsure why this file is causing an error.
The error I'm getting is

```
wrong argument type Class (expected Module)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bank` can only be defined once, either as a `class` or a `module`.  You probably already have a `Bank` class somewhere else in your app.  If you temporarily remove the `extend Bank` line, go into the Rails console, and check this:

```rb
Bank.class
```

If that returns `Class` then it means your app has already defined `Bank` as a class.  You'll need to choose a different module name for your routes, like `Banks`:

```rb
module Banks
  def self.extended(router)
    ...
```

Comment: Gotcha, yeah it returned class, thanks for the quick reply.